# Light Statusbar icons won't change to dark when using LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or LAYOUT_STABLE UI flags?

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-statusbar

So I have a problem with my app's `status bar` not changing its icons to dark when I'm forcing my app into a Light Theme.

I've discovered the root of the issue, which is that the icons in the `status bar` don't want to change dark when I have the `SYSTEM_UI` flags `LAYOUT_STABLE` and `LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN` applied to the `Activity`. When I remove these 2 flags, the icons in the `status bar` are properly dark.

But my problem with this "solution" above is that I am using the 2 `SYSTEM_UI` flags in order to have my Activity's content scroll below the `status bar`, which I have made semi-transparent. I have not figured out another way to make my `status bar` accept transparency and have content scroll below it other than using the 2 `SYSTEM_UI` flags I currently have for this `Activity`, which are, again `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE` and `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN`.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I can get around this issue?

Perhaps someone can show me a reliable way to have my `status bar` accept transparency and have content seen scrolling below it without having to use the `SYSTEM_UI` flags? That would likely solve my problem, I think...

The only code I could think would be relevant to share is this:

In my **MainActivity.java**, I have this set:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);`
```

And in my **styles.xml**, I have this theme set for the `Light Theme`:

```
<!-- Toolbar/NoActionBar variant of default Light Theme -->
<style name="AppTheme_Light_NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/pure_white_transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/pure_white_transparent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/pure_white_transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/pure_white</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
</style>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out on my own. It looks like I probably was needing to set the `SYSTEM_UI` flags before calling `setContentView`. Though, it could be a combination of these changes that made it work for me - I'm not entirely sure.

What I changed was using these flags before calling `setContentView`:

```
if (lightMode) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Light_NoActionBar);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility
               (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR | 
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
    }
```

`lightMode` above is a `SharedPreference` boolean I have set if the user has selected the `Change theme` button in my app's `toolbar` (works the same way for the dark mode/theme).

And finally, for my `MainActivity`'s theme, I have this style set in my `styles.xml` (for API 27 and above - looks a bit different for lower Android APIs' `styles.xml`):

```
<!-- Toolbar/NoActionBar variant of default Light Theme -->
<style name="AppTheme_Light_NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/pure_white_transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/pure_white_transparent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/pure_white_transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/pure_white_transparent</item>
</style>
```

Because it would appear to me that setting the `SYSTEM_UI` flags to `LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN` and `LAYOUT_STABLE` makes the `toolbar` sit underneath the `statusbar`, I've set some appropriate padding by way of:

`int statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight(this);`
Where `getStatusBarHeight` is a method used to account for the possibly varying sizes of `statusbars` on different Android devices (such as the Pixel 3XL's larger `statusbar`).

I got this working method from elsewhere on StackOverflow, but forgot where, so if anyone knows, feel free to link it - method below:

```
    // Gets the StatusBar's height of the particular display.
    public static int getStatusBarHeight(final Context context) {
        final Resources resources = context.getResources();
        final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                return (int) Math.ceil(24 * resources.getDisplayMetrics().density);
            } else {
                return (int) Math.ceil(25 * resources.getDisplayMetrics().density);
            }
        }
}
```

I've then taken the value of `int statusBarHeight` and used it as the top margin for my `toolbar` programatically:

```
// Setup the values for the toolbar's layout parameters.
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams toolbarParams = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    toolbarParams.setMargins(0, statusBarHeight, 0, 0);

    // Find, Assign, and Setup the Toolbar to take place of the Actionbar.
    // Then inflate the proper menu to be used on-top of it, and set its layout parameters
    // which have been set in the code above.
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setLayoutParams(toolbarParams);
```

Finally, I've made sure my app's `RecyclerView` is properly sitting below both the `statusbar` and the `toolbar`, which I have accomplished by setting the appropriate padding to it, also programatically:

```
// Get and set the values for the OffsetPadding for the RecyclerView to int.
    int itemOffsetPaddingSide = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.item_offset);
    int actionBarSize = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.actionbarSizeWithExtraPadding);
    int itemOffsetPaddingTop = actionBarSize + statusBarHeight;
    // Set all the OffsetPadding values to the RecyclerView programmatically, so that
    // all the UI elements are padding properly, taking into account the devices screen
    // density/size/resolution!
    mRecyclerView.setPadding(itemOffsetPaddingSide, itemOffsetPaddingTop, itemOffsetPaddingSide, itemOffsetPaddingSide);
```

The value of `int itemOffsetPaddingSide` is `4dp`, for `int actionBarSize` it's `60dp` and for `int itemOffsetPaddingTop`, by combining both `actionBarSize` and `statusBarHeight`, we get `56dp` plus however tall the `statusBar` for the particular device is (because of the values retrieved and assigned to `statusBarHeight` in the code further up the post).

This all allows for my `RecyclerView`'s content to sit comfortably below the `statusbar` and `toolbar` and also to be visible while scrolling underneath both of them, due to both `bars` having `90% opacity`.

I've been studying Java programming and Android app development for nearly 2 years now independently, and while I'm proud of where I've come in this time, I'm also not sure this is the most elegant way to accomplish this effect in my app. But either way, it works, and if you find it useful for your app too, let me know!